# PHP Generate random number

Tags: php, html

Okay, so I found this code online:

```
<?
$seed = floor(time()/(60*5));
srand($seed);
$item = rand(0,9);
echo $item;
?>
```

That is going to generate a random number every 5 minutes. How can I make it so that it generates to the tenth place? Like instead of 5 it can generate to 5.56 or something like that? Also, how can I make it so that it generates a number close to the old number? For example: the current number is 5.75. It will generate a number close to 5.75 like 5.78 and not 8.52?

Thanks,

Comment: Note that the first decimal after the `.` is the tenth's place. The second decimal after the `.` is the hundred's place. I also found an answer to your question with [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=php+generate+random+number+within+range&gws_rd=ssl). The first link had helpful documentation.

Comment: @jsve, I suspect you meant "hundredths" rather than "hundreds", yes?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a random number to a sub-unit precision by using something like:

```
$item = rand(0,999) / 100;
```

That'll give you something like `0.00` through `9.99`.

You can get a number *close* to the previous by simply adding a small signed offset instead of generating a brand new number, such as:

```
$addthing = (rand(0,10) - 5) / 100;
$item = $item + $addthing;
```

That'll give you a new number within about `0.05` of the previous number. If you want to ensure the number is still in the valid range, you'll have to "clamp" it afterwards. In other words, if `$item` is `0.00` and `$addthing` becomes `-0.02`, you'll obviously end up with a negative number.

How you handle that is up to you but the simplest way is probably just to check the final value of `$item` and force it back into the correct range if it's outside that range.

A good snippet to start with would be:

```
<?php
    $item = rand(0,999) / 100;
    echo $item . "\n";
    $addthing = (rand(0,10) - 5) / 100;
    $item = $item + $addthing;
    if (($item < 0) || ($item > 9.99)) {
        $item = $item - $addthing * 2;
    }
    echo $item . "\n";
?>
```

though it may be better in a function. Note the `if` statement which checks if the final value is outside the valid range and fixes that by subtracting two of the `$addthing` values. Effectively, that means if the addition would result in being outside the range, it subtracts it instead.